# Rounding float to nearest integer in C

Tags: c

I might have a noob question here, but searching the site hasn't yelded anything. I'm learning to program in C and I'm trying to build  a function from scratch that rounds floats to the nearest integer, without using math.h. Here's my code:

```
void main()
{
    float b;
    for(b = 0; b <= 2; b = b + 0.1)
    {
        printf("%f    ", b);
        printf("%i    ", (int)b);
        printf("%f    ", b - (int)b);
        printf("Nearest: ");
        if((b - (int)b)<0.5)
            printf("%i    ", (int)b);
        else
            printf("%i    ", (int)b + 1);
        printf("Function: %i    ", round_near(b));
        printf("\n");
    }
    getchar();
}

int round_near(float b)
{
    if((b - (int)b)<0.5)
        return(int)b;
    else
        return (int)b + 1;
}
```

My results looks like this:

[image]

Some of the code is superfluous and was just meant to see some of the individual steps of my function.
What gives? Are there some shenanigans with float type variables I'm not aware of?

Comment: work: http://ideone.com/TLKAiL

Comment: Don't forget negatives...

Comment: @EugeneSh. in what case will `(int)b` be greater than `b`?

Comment: Yes (yes is too short for comment..)

Comment: `void main()` --> `int main(void)`

Comment: Fair enough, I stand corrected

Comment: @CoryKramer: It's a bitch, I agree ... ;-)

Comment: Why the downvote? It's a complete question.

Comment: I think it's an *awesome* question.  If I were to teach someone this obscure part of C, I couldn't do better than using this question as an example.

Comment: to round, use `return b > 0 ? b + 0.5f : b - 0.5f;`. 0.1 is a `double` literal, you need to use the `f` suffix. Anyway, using steps of 0.1 in binary floating-point is not a good solution

Comment: Thanks for the formatting, guys.
@LưuVĩnhPhúc I wouldn't normally use float in a for loop, it was only meant to generate a set of numbers with decimals I could test my function on

Answer (score 7):

You don't have a prototype for `int round_near(float b)`, so you're relying on implicit declarations.

Try adding this to your code.

```
int round_near (float b); // Prototype

int main(void) // Nitpick: main returns an int!
```

Using implicit declarations for `round_near(b)`, `b` is being promoted to a *double*.  But the definition assumes it's a *float*, which has a different binary layout, so you get crazy random results.

You should make sure your code compiles without any warnings to avoid this sort of stuff.  The only reason implicit declaration is in the language is for backwards compatibility, but every compiler for the last decade or two warns you that it's bad on compile.

Comment: It stands: Still the only complete answer.

Comment: _cringe_  I hadn't thought to check if I included my prototype. Classic rookie mistake. 

Still, it's intersting, I wasn't aware that floats and doubles aren't easily interchangeable. I thought one was just a shorter version of the other, like int and long int.

Side question, why is `int main(void)` better than `void main()`?

Comment: 90% of the time they are interchangeable.  But they do have different memory layouts (floats are 32 bits, doubles are 64 bits) and you've found a case where you end up shoving a double into a float's memory layout, so bugs.

Comment: As for main returning an int: http://stackoverflow.com/a/207992/3294441

Note that the return of your main function is seen by the operating system and by convention, `return 0;` indicates program success while non-zero indicates some sort of failure.

Comment: If my question answered your question, please accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

When I tried to compile this under gcc I got the following error:

```
/tmp/x1.c:23: error: conflicting types for ‘round_near’
/tmp/x1.c:23: note: an argument type that has a default promotion can’t match an empty parameter name list declaration
/tmp/x1.c:16: error: previous implicit declaration of ‘round_near’ was here
```

The funny results you're getting is because your compiler didn't know the definition of `round_near` at the time it was first encountered and assumed it was `int round_near()`.  So this resulted in undefined behavior.

If you either move `round_near` above main or put in a declaration above main you should get the expected results.

Comment: Why undefined behaviour, please?

Answer (score 2):

[@QuestionC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31298985/2410359) well answered OP's immediate problem: implied function signature of `int round_near(...)` is incompatible with `int round_near(float b)` and call of `round_near(b)` which passes `b` as a `double`.

Simple solution: prototype the function.

Some issues about the `round_near()`

1. Casting to `int` severely narrows the legitimate range.  Better to use `long long`.
2. General incorrect functionality with negative numbers. [@Eugene Sh.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4253229/eugene-sh)  Code should test for sign.

Below is a solution that takes advantage of the range of `long long` as it is usually greater than the continuous range of integers a `float` can represent exactly.  Alternatively OP can replace `my_roundf()` with `round_near()` and use this code for testing.   `round_near()` fails about 40% of the time.

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

float my_roundf(float x) {
  // Large `float`s typically have no fractional portion to round
  if (x > LLONG_MAX / 2) return x;
  if (x < LLONG_MIN / 2) return x;
  return x > 0 ? (long long) (x + 0.5f) : (long long) (x - 0.5f);
}

float rand_float(void) {
  union {
    unsigned char uc[sizeof(float)];
    float f;
  } u;
  do {
    unsigned i;
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(float); i++) {
      u.uc[i] = rand();
    }
  } while (u.f != u.f);  // re-do if NaN encountered
  return u.f;
}

void my_roundf_test(void) {
  unsigned n = 100000;
  while (n-- > 0) {
    float x = rand_float();
    float ymath = roundf(x);
    // float ymy = round_near(x);
    float ymy = my_roundf(x);
    // Exact half-way cases may fail
    if (ymath != ymy) {
      printf("x:% .9e math:% .9e my:% .9e\n", x, ymath, ymy);
    }
  }
}
```

Note: There are exact half-way cases per various floating point rounding modes, negative zero, etc. to consider for a complete answer. But leave that for another day.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I hadn't considered that incrementing by 0.5 and rounding down would be the same as rounding to nearest. That's clever. I also hadn't even considered using long long instead of int since I mostly use float to express small rational numbers rather than large numbers. The negative numbers was a total oversight.

Answer (score 0):

A simple one (`float` won't fit in an `int` type, so `long long`)

```
long long round(float a) {
    long long b = a;
    if (a >= 0)
        return a - b < 0.5 ? b : b + 1;
    else
        return b - a < 0.5 ? b : b - 1;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Output like -241... instead of 1 or 2 usually denote uninitialized integers... 
However, your code compiles just fine with GNU C compiler (gcc) on Linux, only after either moving the `round_near` function BEFORE the `int main()` or simply inserting a blank definition of that function (as `int round_near(float b);`) before the `int main()` -- that is "prototyping".

Otherwise, your function will be "seen" as `int round_near()` (see the lack of argument definition) and hence the uninitialized integers printed out by the program.

On the other, such a practice won't produce portable code, so without the modifications bellow your (actually C) code may compile in Visual Studio ... but not with other compilers.

Just another off-topic: don't use floats in `for` loops. Floats are nasty!

Comment: Without prototyping of proper definition before <code>int main()</code> your function will be called as <code>int round_near()</code> instead of <code>int round_near(1.2)</code>. See the difference? b is discarded, so no value for argument b => no value for (int)b and so on...

Comment: This "*your function will be called as `int round_near()` instead of `int round_near(1.2)`*" is not correct. C is different. The issue is not the missing prototype, but the `float` getting promoted to `double` (see *QuestionC*'s answer below). If the OP would have coded `round_near(double f)` the code would work fine, even without the prototype.